# java's e.printStackTrace equivalent in haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell

I am trying out haskell's kafka library from git and got this [error](https://github.com/tcrayford/hafka/issues/2). 
To debug this error, i like to print stacktrace at the error line.

In python world, it is just,

```
import traceback; print traceback.print_exc()
```

(or) in java, it is

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

So, how to do the same in haskell world?

Comment: The wiki page on debugging might have an answer for you: https://wiki.haskell.org/Debugging

Comment: Haskell errors usually tell all tales. I've never ever found a Haskell error that can't be solved using only the error message. The actual error is saying that a value of `Left something` was given, so it must fail. I've posted my response on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get stack traces in Haskell but it is not as convenient as just `e.printStackTrace()`. Here is a minimal example:

```
import Control.Exception
import Debug.Trace

getStack :: String -> SomeException -> IO a
getStack msg e = traceStack (show e) $ error msg

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (head []) `catch` (getStack "error on main at head")
```

Finally, compile it with `ghc -prof -fprof-auto StackTrace.hs` and it will produce

```
Prelude.head: empty list              
Stack trace:                          
  Main.getStack (StackTrace.hs:5:9-56)     
  Main.main (StackTrace.hs:(8,9)-(9,74))   
  GHC.List.CAF (<entire-module>)      
StackTrace.exe: error on main at head
```

Comment: Arbus, How did you run this? i did `runhaskell file.hs` and it printed `Prelude.head: empty list
st.hs: error on main at head
`... did you use ghc or runhaskell?

Comment: ah sorry, forgot to mention that you have to compile this like so: `ghc -prof -fprof-auto StackTrace.hs`, edited the answer now